# How can I discard all merge conflicts in a Git cherry-pick?

Tags: git

I just ran a Git cherry-pick and got some merge conflicts. I've got 5 files listed as changes to be committed and I want to keep them. I've got another 20 or so in unmerged paths that I want to discard. Not all of those have an "ours' equivalent. How can I simply discard all the changes in the unmerged paths here, preferably without specifying the files themselves to discard?